# How access those values in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got this Container Component (parent) and child component.  I'm building my app with Container Component pattern (I try :) ).

So, parent takes all state handling, while child only accepts props and based on them displays output.
But, I came to this small issue: Child displays 2 buttons (+ and -) and two radio buttons (call them 1 and 2). Based on which radio is checked, I need to update state at parent.

I thought about doing it through ref, but I'll stay with good practices and avoid using it.
Other idea I thought about was to pass the function that is being called on button press (binded to parent), but I see no way of calling this function with argument passed in child component.

Child:

```
<label><input type='radio' name='time'/> Work time</label>
<label><input type='radio' name='time' /> Break time</label>
<button onClick={this.props.valueControl} className='add'>+</button>
<button onClick={this.props.valueControl} className='sub'>-</button>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What's your issue with using refs?

Comment: They're consider as bad practice, so I avoid using them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you would communicate with the parent from your child component is via callbacks passed in using properties:

in Parent.js:

```
...
  someEventOccured(event) {
    this.modifyState();
  }

  render() {
     ...
     <child-component onSomeEvent={this.someEventOccured.bind(this)}>
     ...
  }
}
```

in Child.js:

```
...
  render() {
    ...
    <button onClick={this.props.onSomeEvent}></button>
    ...
  }
}
```

In real life, you would probably attach a method of Child to the onClick that processes the event and sends only the data back to the Parent instead of the whole event.

Comment: Yeah, but my question is: How do I get values from child components? Like, I'd like to check which radio button is checked in child component, so I can decide which number to increase value. How do I do this in function passed down to child?

Comment: If you need to access values from the child that means that you're storing the state in the wrong controller. Parents should be notified via callbacks of the changes that affect them. If you want to query the state of a child without anything happening within that child that means that the state should live in the parent.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I've manage to do it, silly me :) I've added one more function from parent to be fired on children on input click. Works excellent :)